# Prompt an alert message box in Extjs

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, extjs

In my UI, I have an EditorGridPanel and a three buttons namely: 'add','save' and 'cancel'. Currently, whenever I want to edit the existing data in my grid and click the save button, automatically it will update the data and that is my problem. I want is to add an alert message box saying 'Do you want to save changes?' If YES, proceed in executing save function. If NO, return the data on its original form before updating the data in the Grid.

Could someone help me about this?

This are my codes:

test.js

```
  var grid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({

                id: 'maingrid',
                store: store,

                cm: cm,


                width: 785.5,
                anchor: '100%',
                height: 700,

                frame: true,
                loadMask: true,
                waitMsg: 'Loading...',
                clicksToEdit: 2,
                tbar: [

                    '->',
                {
                    text: 'Add',
                    iconCls: 'add',  
                    id: 'b_add',
                    disabled: true,                        
                    handler : function(){          
                        var Put = grid.getStore().recordType;
                        var p = new Put({  
                            action_take: 'add',
                            is_active: '',
                            allowBlank: false
                        });
                        Ext.getCmp('b_save').enable();
                        Ext.getCmp('b_cancel').enable();
                        grid.stopEditing();
                        store.insert(0, p);
                        grid.startEditing(0, 1);                        
                        }

                },'-',{
                    text: 'Save',
                    iconCls: 'save',
                    id: 'b_save',
                    disabled: true,
                    handler : function(){
                        var objectStore = Ext.getCmp("maingrid").getStore();
                        var objectModified = objectStore.getModifiedRecords();

                         var customer_id = Ext.getCmp("maingrid").getStore().baseParams['customer_id'];
                         var objectData = new Array();
                         var dont_include;
                         if(objectModified.length > 0)
                         {
                            for(var i = 0; i < objectModified.length; i++)
                            {
                                dont_include = false;                                   


                                    if(objectModified[i].data.id                                            
                                        &&
                                        (
                                        (objectModified[i].data.firstname == undefined || objectModified[i].data.firstname == null|| objectModified[i].data.firstname == '')
                                        ||
                                        (objectModified[i].data.lastname == undefined || objectModified[i].data.lastname == null|| objectModified[i].data.lastname == '')
                                        ||
                                        (objectModified[i].data.email_address == undefined || objectModified[i].data.email_address == null|| objectModified[i].data.email_address == '')
                                        )
                                    )
                                    {
                                        Ext.Msg.show({
                                           title: 'Warning',
                                           msg: "Input value required.",
                                           icon: Ext.Msg.WARNING,
                                           buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                                        });

                                        return;                                      
                                    }
                                     else//no id, means new record
                                     {
                                        //all fields are not filled-in, just do nothing

                                        if((objectModified[i].data.firstname == undefined || objectModified[i].data.firstname == null|| objectModified[i].data.firstname == '')&&
                                        (objectModified[i].data.lastname == undefined || objectModified[i].data.lastname == null|| objectModified[i].data.lastname == '')&&
                                        (objectModified[i].data.email_address == undefined || objectModified[i].data.email_address == null|| objectModified[i].data.email_address == ''))
                                        {
                                            //boolean flag to determine whether to include this in submission
                                            dont_include = true; 
                                        }
                                        //either one field is not filled-in prompt to fill in all fields


                                        else if((objectModified[i].data.firstname == undefined || objectModified[i].data.firstname == null|| objectModified[i].data.firstname == '')||
                                        (objectModified[i].data.lastname == undefined || objectModified[i].data.lastname == null|| objectModified[i].data.lastname == '')||
                                        (objectModified[i].data.email_address == undefined || objectModified[i].data.email_address == null|| objectModified[i].data.email_address == ''))
                                        {
                                            Ext.Msg.show({
                                               title: 'Warning',
                                               msg: "Input value required.",
                                               icon: Ext.Msg.WARNING,
                                               buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                                            });

                                            return;
                                        }

                                     }

                                     //the data for submission
                                     if(!dont_include)
                                     {
                                         objectData.push({
                                            firstname: objectModified[i].data.firstname,
                                            lastname: objectModified[i].data.lastname,
                                            email_address: objectModified[i].data.email_address,
                                            id: objectModified[i].data.id, 
                                            customer_id: customer_id

                                         });
                                     }
                            }
                           // console.log(objectData)
                            // return;

                            //check if data to submit is not empty
                            if(objectData.length < 1)//empty
                            {
                                Ext.Msg.show({
                                    title: 'Warning',
                                    msg: "No records to be saved",
                                    icon: Ext.Msg.WARNING,
                                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                                });

                                Ext.getCmp('maingrid').getStore().reload();

                                return;
                            }
                            // return;
                            Ext.Msg.wait('Saving Records...');
                            Ext.Ajax.request({
                                timeout:900000,
                                params: {objdata: Ext.encode(objectData)},
                                url: '/index.php/SaveContent',
                                success: function(resp){ 
                                    var response = Ext.decode(resp.responseText);
                                    Ext.Msg.hide();
                                    if(response.success == true){  
                                        Ext.Msg.show({
                                            title: "Information",
                                            msg: response.msg,
                                            buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                                            icon: Ext.Msg.INFO,
                                            fn: function(btn){
                                                Ext.getCmp('maingrid').getStore().reload();
                                                Ext.getCmp('b_save').disable();
                                                Ext.getCmp('b_cancel').disable();

                                            }
                                        });
                                    }else{

                                        Ext.Msg.show({
                                            title: "Warning",
                                            msg: response.msg,
                                            buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                                            icon: Ext.Msg.WARNING
                                        });
                                    }
                                },
                                failure: function(resp){  
                                    Ext.Msg.hide();
                                    Ext.Msg.show({
                                        title: "Warning1",
                                        msg: response.msg,
                                        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                                        icon: Ext.Msg.WARNING
                                    });
                                }
                            });


                         }
                         else{
                             Ext.Msg.show({
                                    title: 'Warning',
                                    msg: "No changes made.",
                                    icon: Ext.Msg.WARNING,
                                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                             });

                         }  
                        }
                    },'-',
                     {
                      text: 'Cancel',
                      iconCls: 'cancel',
                      id: 'b_cancel',
                      disabled: true,

                      handler : function(){

                        var store = Ext.getCmp('maingrid').getStore();
                        var modified = store.getModifiedRecords();                      
                        if (modified.length) {
                             Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Cancel', 'There are records not yet saved. Are you sure you want to cancel the changes?', function(btnId) {
                         if (btnId == 'yes') {
                                 store.reload();
                                 Ext.getCmp('b_save').disable();
                                 Ext.getCmp('b_cancel').disable();    
                                 }
                         });
                            }                           

                      }
                   }                       

            ],
            bbar: pager




    });
```

actions.class.php

```
   public function executeSaveContent(sfWebRequest $request){
   $save_data = json_decode($request->getParameter("objdata"));
   $count_array = count($save_data);
   $id_insession = $_SESSION['employee_id'];


   if($count_array > 0){
    foreach($save_data as $k => $v){
        $id = strip_tags($v->id);
        $firstname =  preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $v->firstname);
        $firstname = ltrim(addslashes(strip_tags($firstname)));
        $firstname = rtrim($firstname);
        $lastname =  preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $v->lastname);
        $lastname = ltrim(addslashes(strip_tags($lastname)));
        $lastname = rtrim($lastname);
        $email_address =  preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $v->email_address);
        $email_address = ltrim(addslashes(strip_tags($email_address)));
        $email_adsress = rtrim($email_address);
        $customer_id = $v->customer_id;
        $action = ''; //strip_tags($v->action);
        if(empty($id))
        {
            $action='add';
        }
        else {
            $action='edit';
        }

         if(!empty($firstname)||($lastname)||($email_address)){

             $sql_check = "select firstname,lastname,email_address 
                     from 
                         customer_saver
                    ";
            if($action == "edit"){
                 $sql_check .= " where
                       firstname = '$firstname'
                      and 
                      id not in ($id)";
            }
             if($action == "add"){
                  $sql_check .= " where
                       firstname = '$firstname'
                       ";
             }

         }  




        $setpath = _appContract::SchemaChange('contract_arbill');
        $this->conn->execute($setpath);
        $result_check = $this->conn->fetchAll($sql_check);
            foreach($result_check as $v){

                $fetch_firstname = $this->formatString($v['firstname']);
                $fetch_lastname = $this->formatString($v['lastname']);
                $fetch_email_address= $v['email_address'];
            }
        $result_check_count = count($result_check);

        if($action == "edit"){
            if($result_check_count == 0){
                $sql = "update 

                    customer_saver

                    set

                    firstname = '$firstname',
                    lastname = '$lastname',
                    email_address = '$email_address'                       
                    where
                    id = $id";


            }
            else{
                    $resp['success'] = false;
                    $resp['msg'] = "Duplicate entry found. <br>
                                   First name: <b>".$firstname."</b> Last name: <b>".$lastname."</b> Email Address: <b>".$email_address."</b>";      

                    die(json_encode($resp)); 
            }                
        }

        elseif($action == "add"){
            if(empty($id) && $result_check_count == 0){
                $sql = "insert into 

                    customer_saver

                    (firstname, lastname, email_address,customer_id)
                    values
                    ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email_address', $customer_id)";

            }
            else{
                $resp['success'] = false;
                $resp['msg'] = "Duplicate entry found. <br>
                                First Name: <b>".$firstname."</b> Last Name: <b>".$lastname."</b> Email Address: <b>".$email_address."</b>";      
                die(json_encode($resp)); 
            }
        }
        try{
        $this->conn->execute($setpath);
        $this->conn->execute($sql);
        }catch(Exception $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

        $resp['success'] = true;
        $resp['msg'] = "Successfully saved the record.";      
        die(json_encode($resp));
  }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For displaying confirmation dialog you can use `Ext.MessageBox.confirm()` method.

Then if user click on **Yes** button you can call `store.sync()` method or process your own changes saving.

If user click on **No** button you can call `Ext.data.Store` [`rejectChanges()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-rejectChanges) method. This method rejects outstanding changes on all modified records and re-insert any records that were removed locally.

```
{
    text: 'Save',
    iconCls: 'save',
    id: 'b_save',
    disabled: true,
    handler : function(){
       var store = Ext.getCmp("maingrid").getStore();
       Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Save changes', 'Do you want save changes?', function(btnId) {
           if (btnId == 'yes') {

               // Your current save button handler code               

           } else {
               store.rejectChanges();
           }
       }); 
   }
}
```

Comment: where can I insert this one?

Comment: In your save button handler.

Comment: nothings change, do I need to change something in your code?

Comment: I've updated code in my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: It works now but the problem is that if I add a new record(not edit),the message box will prompt again in fact I only add a new record and not edit.

Comment: You can check if store contains edited records by `store.getUpdatedRecords()`. Also if you want, after user click on No button, reject only edited records and keep newly added you can not use `store.rejectChanges();` In this case you should loop over updated records and call on them `reject` method - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-reject